# Is it possible for Scala to use a specific version of a plugin (addSbtPlugin in plugins.sbt)?

Tags: scala, sbt

We define the plugins in file project/plugins.sbt using addSbtPlugin.

As far as I know when adding dependencies in build.sbt we can force to use some specific version of a library using force().

Is there something similar for addSbtPlugin?

Comment: doesn't `addSbtPlugin` already receives de version you want?

Comment: yes, that's right. The thing is I'm using a plugins which is compatible with play framework 2.8 and sbt 1.3: plugin version is 0.9. But I have another project with play v2.6.5 and sbt 0.13 so the right version for the plugin would be 0.6. This is when I want to force to use version 0.9 of the plugin instead of 0.6 ...

Comment: I do not understand, if the right version is `0.6` why do you want to force it to use `0.9`? And even so, doesn't just change the version in the file should be enough to make the change?

Comment: But sbt 0.13.x is using Scala 2.10 and sbt 1.x is using Scala 2.12 - with such huge difference in version numbers there probably won't be a release of `0.9` that works with 0.13. Why won't you update the older project to match the new one? 0.13 is basically dead now.

Comment: I understand Mateusz, the thing is I can't right now upgrade sbt and playframework, this is one of the constraints I have ... That was my first idea, why we don't upgrade the project? But the answers was "no, we can't do it at this time, let's see if we can make work this plugin with sbt 0.13 and play 2.6.5 ..."